# shift/offset scene with orbitcontrol

Tags: three.js

is there a way to offset a scene center pointer without having to make my canvas bigger? I have a canvas at 100% of the width but I got some floating legend content that takes up about 25% of the width and I want my focus object center to be at 37.5% instead of 50%. The only way I can do it is by making my width 125% and position my canvas to the left by -25%. Thanks,

jk

Comment: Can you not put your canvas and menu in separate divs and position them with css?

Comment: The legend div is floating and I want the 3D scene to take up 100% of the width of my screen as it's part of the backgrount but I cannot figure how to shift the center point without increasing the width.

Comment: Having a look at the [source of OrbitControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) it seems to have a `target` that accepts a Vector3D. Try setting that.